# create a drool rule with xml input, need a boolean logic that is not working inside esb

Tags: xml, drools, esb

I have the following code

```
rule "Routing Rule to ReminderSend using XPATH"
when
    xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP']) + count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "2"
then 
    Log : "ReminderSend" ;
    Destination : "ReminderSend";
end
```

But this will not work when i have multiple items in pick up

I need to have an `AND` statement in this rule but i cant seem to make this work
I need the following condition to be true

```
(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP']) and (/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])
```

the problem is that sometimes `IsPICKUPReminder` is present in some xml and sometimes its not, so I have to check for null value

Comment: This isn't proper Drools syntax. It may be written in some DSL, but then asking questions without knowing the DSL definition is futile. And the tag `esb` refers to Enterprise Service Bus, which most certainly isn't applicable here.

Comment: i just need to change my rule to be with an and statement i'm not familiar with this syntax and just adding a new rule

Comment: Maybe I can guess how this DSL works - but I'll need an XML example illustrating what you need to match *in terms of XML* and as described by your phrase "multiple items in pick up". Edit your question and alert me with another comment.

Comment: Here is an example of an xml. ISPICKUPREminder flag is not always present and i need to be able to check when its not there:

Comment: <OrderLineList IsPICKUPReminder="Y">
    <Extn ExtnShipGroupId="sgxxxxxxx" ExtnShippingCouponCode=""
ExtnShippingGroupDistrictTax=""
        ExtnShippingGroupStateTax="" ExtnShippingPromotionId=""
        ExtnShippingQuantityAdjusted="" ExtnShippingTotalAdjustment="" ExtnShippingUnitAdjustment=""/>
    <OrderLine FulfillmentType="PICK-UP"
        GiftWrap="N" Status="PICK-UP"> there can be multiple up pickups

Comment: Honestly i'm having problems with my sytnax I need the following rule to work: "/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType ='PICK-UP']" and "OrderLineList.@IsPICKUPReminder[0]!"N""

Comment: You should at least be able to refer to XML elements by their real name ("item" must be an Order, "in a pick up" is in an OrderLine).

Comment: How come you have to modify some software without having the slightest idea how its syntax is defined? No reference to any documentation?

Comment: nothing is documented

Comment: Any other rules in there? See anything else but xpathEquals in the corresponding position?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess - there *may* be an operator xpathGreater or there may not. If this doesn't work and you can't produce any kind of guideline or reference for how these rules need to be written I'll just delete this answer.

```
rule "Routing Rule to ReminderSend using XPATH"
when
    xpathGreater  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0"
    xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "1"
then 
    Log : "ReminderSend" ;
    Destination : "ReminderSend";
end
```

Comment: i was asked to add a subject line change which i can only do by modifying this rule, which i have no idea how to use and i cant find any reference to where they even got any of this from, if anybody would suggest or point me in the direction

Comment: its so silly but its true i have no clue on this syntax and after getting the count to work i realized that my logic is wrong and i need the "and" operator no matter how i play with this and i cant figure out the and operator

Comment: There is an "and" operator implied in (original) Drools by different CEs just being written one after the other. Did you try this?

Comment: rule "Routing Rule to ReminderSend using XPATH"
 when
  xpathMatch "/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType ='PICK-UP']"
  xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "1"
 then 
  Log : "ReminderSend";
  Destination : "ReminderSend";
 end
 
 
rule "Routing Rule to Send using XPATH"
 when
  xpathMatch "/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType ='PICK-UP']"
  xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "0"
 then 
  Log : "Send";
  Destination : "Send";
 end keeps failing

Comment: YES! These rules confirm that an "and" is achieved by writing one conditional element `xpathXXXX` after the other - as in the original Drools DRL language. Maybe there is an xpathGreater...

Comment: there is xpathGreaterThan, does the xpathXXXX have to be the same, as in i cant use xpathMatch and next line xpathEquals.

Comment: can ask one more question as to how to check a null value on IsPICKUPReminder

Comment: I continue to error out on the below code when
  xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0"
  xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "0"

Comment: I think the better solution would just be one check if the value of ispickup either exists or doesnt exist

Comment: That would be the rules you posted in a comment. ispickup is what? IsPICKUPReminder?

Comment: i keep on going in circles i sort of got it to work, but yet again i always return to my second check which based on everything i read should work but continues to fail when i add another xpath into my condition

Comment: This has become very confusing to me, too. Why don't you create a new question, containing every rule you know to work, with a single condition and with a combination of two conditions. Also, add what does not work, with the corresponding error message.

Comment: attempting to do two checks into one xpath rule in droolsjust posted it, i'm having hard time posting correctly sorry